# Http Handler at website level on IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5

Are there Http Handlers above the level of web applications, i.e. at the IIS web site level or at IIS level?

I have two applications and i want t write an Http Handler to intercept all the requests coming to these two applications and process something upfront and return a response in some cases and redirect in other cases.

do i require http handler or a module here?

Answer (score 0):

You can define them in the [machine.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/index) of the server

Make sure you put the libraries that contains the handlers inside the GAC